# Why does this python code not display the animation?

Tags: python

Please help. I couldn't find what is wrong with my code. The code works, but it doesn't display the animation. I want to display the movement of the planet around the star. But I think there is some problems with the 'update' function. I don't know what's wrong.

```
#항성과 행성이 있을 때 행성이 움직이는 궤도: 원, 타원, 포물선, 쌍곡선.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
R=3.844e8
T=0.5
k=3.959e14
dθ,dt=0.1,0.001
rx,ry=0,-R
vx,vy=R*dθ/dt,0
'''for i in range(0,int(T/dt)):
    ax=-k/((rx[i]**2+ry[i]**2)**1.5)*rx[i]
    ay=-k/((rx[i]**2+ry[i]**2)**1.5)*ry[i]
    vx+=ax*dt
    vy+=ay*dt
    rx.append(rx[i]+vx*dt)
    ry.append(ry[i]+vy*dt)
'''
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0,1e8)
ax.set_ylim(-1e9,1e9)
x,y=[],[]
line,=plt.plot([],[],'bo')
def update(i):
    global vx,vy,rx,ry
    ax=-k/((rx**2+ry**2)**1.5)*rx
    ay=-k/((rx**2+ry**2)**1.5)*ry
    vx+=ax*dt
    vy+=ay*dt
    rx+=vx*dt
    ry+=vy*dt
    x.append(rx)
    y.append(ry)
    line.set_data(rx,ry)
    return line,
ani=FuncAnimation(fig,update,frames=range(0,int(T/dt)))
plt.show()
```

Comment: "The code works, but it doesn't display the animation." in other words -- the code doesn't work.

Comment: something wrong with your update logic, i print rx and ry in each frame, with y=-384400000.0 and rx exceeding 1e9 which is out of your plot margin

Comment: I solved the problem. The animation wasn't displayed because the ranges of axes were too narrow. Also, I did a mistake at 'line.set_data(rx,ry)', which is supposed to be 'line.set_data(x,y)'. If you change that and change ax.set_xlim(0,1e8)->ax.set_xlim(-1e9,1e9) and change the first value of vx, you get the animation of the movement of celestial.